# Are there Gestalt or Hybrid rules for 5e?

Tags: dnd-5e, gestalt

Are there Gestalt or Hybrid rules for D&D 5e?

Comment: We're not going to curate and recommend a list of homebrew rules you might possibly be interested in, so I've removed that from the question. If you want to ask about what homebrew for this is available out there in the wild, that's a question more suited to a [discussion forum](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/q/5449).

Answer (score 14):

No, there are (currently, at least) no gestalt or hybrid rules for D&D 5e. The closest there is is the multiclassing rules.

It's difficult to prove a negative, but rules for gestalt or hybrid characters do not appear in any of the following sourcebooks:

- *Player's Handbook*
- *Monster Manual*
- *Dungeon Master's Guide*
- *Elemental Evil Player's Companion*
- *Sword Coast Adventurer's Guide*
- *Volo's Guide to Monsters*

Likewise, rules for gestalt or hybrid characters have not been featured in any of the [*Unearthed Arcana*](http://dnd.wizards.com/articles-tags/unearthed-arcana) articles.

And, for the sake of completeness, they have also not appeared in any of the official campaign books.